# Xamarin.Forms - Changing values from SQLite before displaying (DateTime)

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a problem and I hope you will help me.

My application in Xamarin.Forms can add to the sqlite:

```
public class Product
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

This data is added using:

```
<Editor Placeholder="Enter text" Text="{Binding Text}" />
<Editor Placeholder="Enter details" Text="{Binding Details}" />
<DatePicker Date="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

On another page, I display them using ListView:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Details}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Date}" />
```

The date is displayed in the format: 01/01/2017 00:00:00

I would like to be able to change this date text before it appears. For example, I would like to convert this string date into a DateTime object and calculate how many days were left from today to the given date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's generally a best practice to store dates as DateTime types in the db, not strings.

That said, there are a lot of ways you could approach this.  One would be to add a read-only property to your model or ViewModel

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    // tell sqlite to ignore this column
    [Ignore]
    public int DaysLeft {
      get {
        // should add error handling here in case
        // date format is bad
        var date = DateTime.Parse(Date);
        // diff will be a TimeSpan
        var diff = DateTime.Now - date;
        // might want to add logic to handle negative values
        return diff.Days;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course, this solved my problem. I used your code and used "Binding DaysLeft" instead of "Binding Date".

Comment: Date adding and display works correctly. Unfortunately, when I want to add a new Item, but I have not selected the date (I do not click on DatePicker) and click Save -> I have an exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: this is a completely different problem - you should ask a new question